# Why does vertica need a swap partition?

Tags: database, vertica

I'm installing Vertica 7.1 on a Centos 6 cluster. Each of my node has 48g mem so swap partition is disabled by default. I don't understand why vertica must have a swap partition. To me it doesn't make sense. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is great that you have 48 Gb of RAM per node but your Vertica cluster doesn't care about that.

You see, Vertica was build to run on top of cheap/commodity hardware that is 4-8 Gb of RAM with 3-4 CPU's, so swap space was needed in this cases unless you have mastered you resource allocation and also your database workload.

You can install the database without the swap space as well just use the **--failure-threshold NONE** option. -- this will come with some penalties in case the swap will be needed.

I recommend having swap space as per Vertica's recommendation, if you don't want that swap to be used unless you RAM reaches 90% then play around with the swappiness linux parameter, see here how is done https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness.

**Also look into Scale-UP vs Scale-OUT.**
By the looks of it you are going for the **Scale-UP** method which i don't recommend because of many point such as :

- cost more to add hardware to a big-box, then to slide in another
  server.
- difficult to admin because of the conflicting needs of all the
  independent process. Big impacts due to inadvertent changes to
  root or patches to sub-systems or OS.
- Costly mis-sizing of hardware that cost your company.

Answer (score 0):

Swap is not just for when you run out of RAM. Lots of services run infrequently and can easily be swapped to disk to free up memory for more important things.  If you don't have at least some swap space, you'll be wasting RAM. I'd rather have my RAM used for disk cache than for services that almost never are executing.

That's probably why Vertica requires a minimal amount of swap space (only 2GB). 
[Doc Link](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/InstallationGuide/BeforeYouInstall/swapspace.htm)

Comment: Nice and interesting story, but still no reason for *requiring* it if the sysadmin decides he has enough RAM. I agree it's a bad choice on his part, but it shouldn't break an installer like this if he's damn sure he has enough physical RAM.

Comment: You can bypass the error in the installer if you want.  Also, I'm not sure I would say 'damn sure' as much as 'stupid enough to'. It's a waste of RAM not to use a minimal swap.

Comment: As said it's still his choice not to have swap. I fully agree it's not really a smart choice, but the software has no reason to prohibit stupid behaviour as it can run fine without swap.

Comment: I agree, it should be his choice, and it is if he instructs the installer to bypass the failure.